# Flutter app crashes when opening a screen with a query in firestore/Storage only in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app, and in one screen, I'm getting content from storage and firestore. With this code I'm able to see a list of links from firestore

```dart
myScreen.dart
//I have another method similar to this to show the content inside folders (read below)
loadBasicStructure(submenu ,callback, context){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: ctrl.loadMain(submenu),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Center(child: Text('Error'));
        } else {
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider();
            },
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
              ItemLab item = snapshot.data[i];
              print(item);
              return ListTile(
                  leading: setIconLab(item),
                  title: Text(setText(item)),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
                  onTap: () async {
                      //mycode
                    }
                  },
                );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

```dart
controller.dart

Future<List<ItemLab>> loadLab(String submenu) async {
    var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child(submenu);
    var ret = await snapshot.listAll();
    List<ItemLab> content = [];
    ret.prefixes.forEach((element) {
      content add(
        Item(
          type: 'FOLDER',
          elemento: element,
        ),
      );
    });

    ret.items.forEach((element) {
      print(element);
      conteudo.add(
        ItemLab(
          type: 'FILE',
          element: element,
        ),
      );
    });

    try{
      await databaseReference
          .collection("${submenu}_url")
          .get()
          .then((snapshot)  {

        snapshot.docs.forEach((f) async => {
          f.data().isNotEmpty ?
            content.add(
              Item(
                type: 'VIDEO',
                element: null,
                video: f.data(),
              ),
            )
          :
            null

        });
      });

      await databaseReference
          .collection("${submenu}_url")
          .doc("Folder")
          .collection("RESET")
          .get()
          .then((snap){
        snap.docs.isNotEmpty ? conteudo.add(
          Item(
              type: FOLDER',
              folderVideo: "RESET"
          ),
        ) : null;
      });

    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }


    return Future.value(content);
  }
```

How this code works:

I have a screen with a list of submenus EX ("submenu1, submenu2"). Inside it I check in storage if in that folder ("submenu1") it has some files and if yes I show in a list, if has not I check if there are folders inside this one ("submenu1 > RESET"). If it exists I show the folder.

I do this exact check too in firestore (because there I store some links from youtube). In this case the error is throwing because I have another screen with only items from firestore (and with the same structure) and it works normally, but in the submenu "photos" when I click in the folder "RESET" the app crashes and show this error:

```
2021-02-01 09:28:22.129581-0300 Runner[391:22847] An error occurred while parsing query arguments, this is most likely an error with this SDK. (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000189afb9ec F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 1157612
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019de81b54 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   Runner                              0x00000001023cddf0 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 304
    3   Runner                              0x00000001023cd90c _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 20
    4   Runner                              0x00000001023dfcf8 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util20ThrowInvalidArgumentIJNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEmEEEvPKcDpRKT_ + 48
    5   Runner                              0x00000001023b8238 _ZN8firebase9firestore3api19CollectionReferenceC2ENS0_5model12ResourcePathENSt3__110shared_ptrINS1_9FirestoreEEE + 716
    6   Runner                              0x00000001023e6684 _ZN8firebase9firestore3api9Firestore13GetCollectionERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE + 104
    7   Runner                              0x00000001023fc0a4 -[FIRFirestore collectionWithPath:] + 112
    8   Runner                              0x00000001025319b4 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader FIRQuery] + 344
    9   Runner                              0x0000000102531428 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader readValueOfType:] + 1272
    10  Flutter                             0x0000000103914130 Flutter + 5685552
    11  Runner                              0x0000000102530fdc -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader readValueOfType:] + 172
    12  Flutter                             0x000000010391564c Flutter + 5690956
    13  Flutter                             0x00000001039121dc Flutter + 5677532
    14  Flutter                             0x00000001033d9f9c Flutter + 204700
    15  Flutter                             0x00000001036b1d88 Flutter + 3186056
    16  Flutter                             0x00000001033e342c Flutter + 242732
    17  Flutter                             0x00000001033e53a0 Flutter + 250784
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000189a7c3e0 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 635872
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000189a7bfe4 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 634852
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000189a7b4c4 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 632004
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000189a75850 F3021642-E3C0-33F8-9911-DD303A6056D0 + 608336
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000189a74ba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001a07dd598 GSEventRunModal + 160
    24  UIKitCore                           0x000000018c3662f4 CC6E5AC7-8248-35F6-8B42-2E25C93DCF0A + 11723508
    25  UIKitCore                           0x000000018c36b874 UIApplicationMain + 164
    26  Runner                              0x000000010239af80 main + 64
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000189753568 0B475C78-3C12-3121-B7F8-2B95B83DAF44 + 5480
)
2021-02-01 09:28:22.130980-0300 Runner[391:22847] -[NSNull getDocumentsWithSource:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d9269ee0
2021-02-01 09:28:22.132261-0300 Runner[391:22847] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull getDocumentsWithSource:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d9269ee0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x189afb9d8 0x19de81b54 0x189a0bbbc 0x189afe01c 0x189afff8c 0x102530514 0x10252e9d0 0x103912224 0x1033d9f9c 0x1036b1d88 0x1033e342c 0x1033e53a0 0x189a7c3e0 0x189a7bfe4 0x189a7b4c4 0x189a75850 0x189a74ba0 0x1a07dd598 0x18c3662f4 0x18c36b874 0x10239af80 0x189753568)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull getDocumentsWithSource:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d9269ee0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

#### Expected behavior

I expect that when I tap in the folder inside submenu, it opens a list of links (like it do in the other submenu that only have storage files

I don't know if i'm being clear, if there are a question, tell me

[Xcode Error Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGNzn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, just drop the part you get content from firestore and see if it works... if yes, put it back. For some reason it might work